# Simple coordinate locations

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am using Xcode, sprite kit, swift.

I have a very simple problem. I use the following code to set an object in the following position:

```
CGPoint(x: world.frame.size.width / 2, y: world.frame.size.height / 2 * 1.6)
```

I now want to place another object in the same location, but reverse the y axis:

```
CGPoint(x: world.frame.size.width / 2, y: world.frame.size.height / 2 * -1.6)
```

But when I run Xcode, I cannot see the -1.6 object? Why won't it appear on the screen?

Cheers :D

Comment: I think you might be trying to do this: 
CGPoint(x: world.frame.size.width / 2, y:  world.frame.size.height - world.frame.size.height / 2 * 1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your second `y` coordinate is negative, you won't see your object.

If `world.frame.size.height` is 200 for example, the caluclation is: `200 / 2 * -1.6` which is `-1600`.

Comment: So how do I create it so that I can have 2 objects the exact same distance apart o the y axis?

Comment: I might need more information for a specific answer, but generally `+` and `-` operations will do: `world.frame.size.height / 2 + 100` and `world.frame.size.height / 2 - 100`.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I just used world.frame.size.height / 5  and then * it by a number to move items upward. So I set the bottom object first :D